# How do I pass credentials to Sonar API calls?

Tags: api, sonarqube

When I try to call:

https://sonar.mydomain.com/api/resources?resource=com.mydomain.project:MY&metrics=ncloc&format=json

I get

```
{"err_code":401,"err_msg":"Unauthorized"}
```

How do I pass my credentials?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API) SonarQube uses *basic authentication*. Try:

```
curl -u admin:SuPeRsEcReT "https://sonar.mydomain.com/api/resources?resource=com.mydomain.project:MY&metrics=ncloc&format=json"
```

Obviously the mechanism for passing these credentials is dependent on how you are invoking the API.

This should also work from the web browser. Try logging into the Webui, your browser will normally cache the credentials.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Do you know:  is this basic authentication?

Comment: The documentation states that SonarQube uses basic authentication

Comment: I am getting 404 when am running via jenkins container. either curl or python

Answer (score 35):

According to the newest [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API) said: SonarQube now support two way authentication:

- **User Token**

**This is the recommended way**. Token is sent via the login field of HTTP basic authentication, this way will be more safety, without any password. For more information about how to generate a token, please visit this page [User Token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token). Use curl send request like this:

```
curl -u THIS_IS_MY_TOKEN: https://sonarqube.com/api/user_tokens/search
# note that the colon after the token is required in curl to set an empty password
```

- **HTTP Basic Access**

Login and password are sent via the standard HTTP Basic fields:

```
curl -u MY_LOGIN:MY_PASSWORD https://sonarqube.com/api/user_tokens/search
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, thanks for the colon reminder.

Comment: what is the http header name if we are authenticating using token?

Comment: Thanks to this answer I found out how to use the SonarClient (Java-lib).
In case others are also trying this, you have to use an empty password:
`SonarClient sonarClient = SonarClient.builder() .url(config.getConnectionUrl()) .login(config.getConnectionToken()) .password("").build();`

Answer (score 6):

This happens because authentication data does not include in your api call. This is how I solved it.

1.First install a rest client "Postman" to your browser.
2.Open it and put your API call url under "Normal" tab.
3.Go to "Basic Auth" tab and put username,password then click refresh headers.
4.Come back to "Normal" tab. You'll see a header named "Authorization" in header list.
5.Now click "send" button to view results.
6.If you are using 3rd party application, add "Authorization" header to your call with the value generated by postman.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you! I just wanted to add that if you're using a token, you just put the token in the username field and leave the password blank. Ref: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/user-token/

Comment: Hey I am trying the same. I first tried adding user token in place of username and left password blank. Selected Basic Auth from authorization tab but everytime I get 401 Unauthorized error even when its a POST HTTP call. I cant authenticate the user. Please help