# Creating projects with SonarQube web api

Tags: sonarqube

Im trying to create a project with SonarQube web api, I can't find any good tutorial to create them.

I need to analyze a code and then get the information that SonarQube provides, I need to automatize all of this in a web application.

Is this possible to do with SonarQube web api?

Answer (score 4):

The latest SonarQube versions have an api-documentation link. For SonarCloud you can find the documentation [here](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api). The documentation to create a new project is [here](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/projects). If you look at the details of *api/projects/create* you can see the parameters needed, the changelog and a response example. This API is available since version 4.0.

Comment: I'm using the web api but get a 401 Unauthorized response in api/projects/create
Is that a permissions problem?
How can I get permissions?

Comment: @CuauhtémocPascacio [This](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API) documentation page explains how to authenticate.See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244163/how-do-i-pass-credentials-to-sonar-api-calls) SO question.